# C++ Virtual Void

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual, void

Okay, so I have a parent class called employee and 3 subclass called manager,researcher and engineer. I made a vector and want to list them. this is the how I process the making.

```
vector <Employee*,Manager*> EmployeeDB;
Employee *temp;

temp = new Manager(first, last, salary, meetings, vacations);
EmployeeDB.push_back(temp);
```

I have no problem in making the vector, my concern is listing the info. all 3 subclasses have `firstname`, `lastname` and `salary` but they're difference is that they have different data members which is unique, example the `Manager` has the `int` value `vacation` and the `Engineer` has the `int` value `experience` so on and so forth.

**Employee.h**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef EMPLOYEE_h
#define EMPLOYEE_h

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee();
    Employee(string firstname, string lastname, int salary);
    string getFname();
    string getLname();
    int getSalary();

    virtual void getInfo();

private:
    string mFirstName;
    string mLastName;
    int mSalary;

};
#endif
```

**Employee.cpp**:

```
#include "Employee.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Employee::Employee()
{
    mFirstName = "";
    mLastName = "";
    mSalary = 0;
}

Employee::Employee(string firstname, string lastname, int salary)
{
    mFirstName = firstname;
    mLastName = lastname;
    mSalary = salary;
}

string Employee::getFname()
{
    return mFirstName;
}

string Employee::getLname()
{
    return mLastName;
}

int Employee::getSalary()
{
    return mSalary;
}

void Employee::getInfo()
{
    cout << "Employee First Name: " << mFirstName << endl;
    cout << "Employee Last Name: " << mLastName << endl;
    cout << "Employee Salary: " << mSalary << endl;
}
```

**Main**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Employee.h"
#include "Engineer.h"
#include "Manager.h"
#include "Researcher.h"
using namespace std;

vector <Employee*> EmployeeDB;
Employee *temp;

void add()
{
    int emp, salary, vacations, meetings, exp, c;
    string first, last, type, school, topic;
    bool skills;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "===========================================" << endl;
        cout << "               Add Employee                " << endl;
        cout << "===========================================" << endl;
        cout << "[1] Manager." << endl;
        cout << "[2] Engineer." << endl;
        cout << "[3] Researcher." << endl;
        cout << "Input choice: ";
        cin >> emp;
        system("cls");
    } while (emp <= 0 || emp > 3);

    cout << "===========================================" << endl;
    cout << "              Employee  Info               " << endl;
    cout << "===========================================" << endl;
    cout << "Employee First name: ";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Employee Last name: ";
    cin >> last;
    cout << "Employee Salary: ";
    cin >> salary;

    switch (emp)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Employee numbers of meetings: ";
        cin >> meetings;
        cout << "Employee numbers of vacations: ";
        cin >> vacations;

        temp = new Manager(first, last, salary, meetings,vacations);
        EmployeeDB.push_back(temp);
        delete temp;

        break;
    case 2:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "[1]YES    [2]NO" << endl;
        cout << "Employee C++ Skills: ";
        cin >> c;
        if (c == 1)
        {
            skills = true;
        }
        else
        {
            skills = false;
        }

        cout << "Employee Years of exp: ";
        cin >> exp;
        cout << "(e.g., Mechanical, Electric, Software.)" << endl;
        cout << "Employee Engineer type: ";
        cin >> type;

        temp = new Engineer(first, last, salary, skills, exp, type);
        EmployeeDB.push_back(temp);
        delete temp;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Employee School where he/she got his/her PhD: ";
        cin >> school;
        cout << "Employee Thesis Topic: ";
        cin >> topic;

        temp = new Researcher(first, last, salary, school, topic);
        EmployeeDB.push_back(temp);
        delete temp;
        break;
    }
}

void del()
{

}

void view()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < (EmployeeDB.size()); x++)
    {
        cout << EmployeeDB[x]->getInfo();
    }
}

void startup()
{

    cout << "===========================================" << endl;
    cout << "             Employee Database             " << endl;
    cout << "===========================================" << endl;
    cout << "[1] Add Employee." << endl;
    cout << "[2] Delete Employee." << endl;
    cout << "[3] List Employees." << endl;
    cout << "[4] Exit." << endl;
    cout << "Please Enter Your Choice: ";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool flag = true;
    int choice;

    do {
        do 
        {
            system("cls");
            system("pause>nul");
            startup();
            cin >> choice;
        } while (choice < 0 || choice >4);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            add();
            break;
        case 2:
            del();
            break;
        case 3:
            view();
            break;
        case 4:
            flag = false;
            system("EXIT");
            break;
        }
    } while (flag == true);

    return 0;
    system("pause>nul");
}
```

I am getting error on the `view()` function.

It says no `operator<<` matches these operands 
binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right hand operand of type void etc etc.

Comment: What are you supposed to store in the vector `EmployeeDB`? Is `Manager` derived from `Employee`? Then *only* use `Employee*` as the type in the vector.

Comment: `getInfo` doesn't return anything. What is the point of trying to pass nothing to `cout`?

Comment: Either implement `operator<<` on `Employee` class or only call `getInfo()` method as it does the couting itself.

Comment: That is because `getInfo` returns nothing. But that is not the biggest problem in your code, you are populating `EmployeeDB` with dangling pointers because you delete object pointed to by just inserted pointer right away `EmployeeDB.push_back(temp); delete temp;`. If you intend to keep pointers then 1) make destructor virtual 2) store `unique_ptr<Employee>` instead of raw pointers 3)allocated them with `make_unique` removing no manual new / delete

Comment: I used void because I just want to cout the values inside that certain vector, example myvector[1] i want to cout the first,last,and salary of this, how do I inplement that?

Comment: I am storing employee type in the vector. the employee is the parent class and the 3 subclass inherits the parent.

Comment: You are storing a pointer to employee base type `vector <Employee*> EmployeeDB`

Comment: yes @VTT yes I have no problem with that sir. I dont know how to output the data members and they have unique data members but my prof requires me to use inheritance and polymorphism

Comment: You can make getInfo virtual and override it in each inheriting class to call base and also output its own unique data fields

Comment: And while you're at it, rename `getInfo` to `displayInfo` and we will all be less confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `getInfo` has return type `void` and you are trying to put that return value into cout.

It's important to understand that the code `std::cout << val` actually calls the function `operator<<(ostream& out, const objectType& val)` where objectType is the type of 'val'.

In your case the type is void, and there is simply no implementation of `operator<<` that takes void as a type. hence the error "no operator found which takes a right hand operand of type void...".

In order to fix your issue you have a few options:

1. Change `view()` to be

   ```
   for (...)
   {
     EmployeeDB[x]->getInfo();
   }
   ```
2. Change `getInfo()` to return a string the info as you'd like:

   ```
   std::string getInfo()
   {
     std::string info;
     info =...
     return info;
   }
   ```
3. Create an `operator<<` for Employee and change view to call it:

   ```
   view()
   {
     for (...)
     {
       std::cout << EmployeeDB[x];
     }
   }
   ```